# How to send & Share a TextView via SMS?

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android.I want to send & Share a `TextView` via SMS.

I am able to send by putting the text in string. But i can not send or share the value using `TextView`.

How can i do this??

here is my code what i am doing..

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final String tv1 = tv.getText().toString();
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("tel:"));
            localIntent.putExtra("sms_body", MainActivity.this.getText(Integer.parseInt(tv1)));
            localIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
        }
    });

    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
            localIntent.setType("text/plain");
            localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", R.string.app_name);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, "Share SMS"));
        }
    });
}
```

i get this error...

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: nextappsbd.sendshare, PID: 3521
                                                                java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "Hello World!"
                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
                                                                    at nextappsbd.sendshare.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:27)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18792)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5344)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:676)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What about getting the String value from `TextView`, then send/share it? otherwise, you can't send/share a view.

Comment: I'm not interested to doing this

Comment: You can't share a View (TextView in your case) via SMS.

Comment: Can i convert the textview to string?

Comment: Sorry @Rami 1st i can not understand what u say..

Comment: It might be possible to send enough information about a TextView to be able to recreate it on the recipient's device, but it would have to be your app receiving the message and recreating the View. An arbitrary SMS client isn't going to know what to do with your message, other than to treat it as a regular message.

Answer (score 0):

```
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final String tv1 = tv.getText().toString();
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("tel:"));
            localIntent.putExtra("sms_body", tv1);
            localIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
        }
    });

    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
            localIntent.setType("text/plain");
            localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", tv1);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, "Share SMS"));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent message = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + "") );
                message.putExtra( "sms_body",Textview.gettext.toString() );
                startActivity(message);
```

try this

Comment: please post your code  so that it can help us to get solution

Comment: localIntent.putExtra("sms_body", MainActivity.this.getText(Integer.parseInt(tv1))); your getting error here rite just add  this localIntent.putExtra("sms_body", tv1);

Comment: actually you are trying to convert the  string to the integer its not possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98349/discussion-between-nakul-and-amit-saha).

Comment: if you had got it rate the answere dont downgrade it.